# Discord.js: How to play music stream from http?

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, discord.js

This is my code:

```js
if (msg.content.includes('*stream')) {
 var name=(msg.content).slice(8,80);
    if (msg.member.voiceChannel) {
      msg.member.voiceChannel.join()
        .then(connection => {
  console.log(name);
    const dispatcher = connection.playFile(name);
  dispatcher.setVolume(0.5); 
        })
        .catch(console.log);
    } else {
      msg.reply('Enter channel first');
    }
  }
```

When I write in Discord `*stream https://play.sas-media.ru/play`, the console shows the full link (`https://play.sas-media.ru/play`), the bot enters the voice channel, but nothing else happens.

What am I doing wrong?